# detectChanges resets reactive form. What is a right way to manage form values in tests?

Tags: angular, testing

I am writing a test for a reactive form.

```
app.form.get('name').setValue('new value');
expect(app.form.get('name').value).toEqual('new value');
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(app.form.get('name').value).toEqual('new value'); // <-- Fails.
```

I debugged it. I see that the control value is resetted to default after `detectChanges`

[There is the case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56284765-angular-form-error-directive-tests?file=app/error-directive.spec.ts)

What is a right way to manage form values in tests?

Comment: This does not sound right to me. The test might be failing because you found a bug.

Comment: This way I show the problem. I do not need to test it.

Comment: can you provide the content of ngOnInit method in your component ? and add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your test, as written can fail for this reason:

`fixture.detectChanges();` will execute `ngOnInit` method and if you are instantiating the `app.form` value inside that lifecycle hook,

then all the fields will get the default value again and the value you just set before with:

```
app.form.get('name').setValue('new value');
```

will be overridden and your test in `expect(app.form.get('name').value).toEqual('new value'); // <-- Fails.` will then fail.

Comment: I checked your comments. It is that way you say https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56284765-angular-form-error-directive-tests?file=app/error-directive.spec.ts But why? ngOnInit has to be invoked once.

Comment: @viktor.likin: if the answer is helpful accept it, ``fixture.detectChanges();`` will run ``ngOnInit`` it's in the official documentation examples.  --> https://angular.io/guide/testing#more-async-tests